# Specify pydantic model fields from a data source

Tags: python-typing, pydantic

I have a need for a pydantic model that would dynamically create model fields from another data source. I'd like to do something like this:

```py
import pydantic
import my_data

_data = my_data.load() # _data[variable] = value

class MyModel(pydantic.BaseModel):

    # this obviously doesn't work. Is there a way to create a suite of variable 
    # names from the keys in _data
    for _key in _data:
        _key: float = None
```

I've tried to do `setattr(MyModel, _key, None)` but that doesn't work either. The tricky business is that there are a few hundred fields that I would like to specify on `MyModel` but I'm not sure how to do this effectivly. How can I create an arbitrary set of fields on a pydantic model based on data in a dictionary? More generally, is there a way to specify class attributes and their associated type hints from data in a dictionary?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve by dynamically creating Pydantic models?

Comment: Are you interested in `pydantic` model only or in static type checking? For model, the answer below is correct. For static checking, there is no simple solution (your best bet would be either `mypy` plugin or codegen).

Comment: @PawełRubin I'm trying to enable static type checking for a list of 200 variables that is likely to grow over the next few years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### My Answer

You can use `pydantic.create_model` and `pydantic.Field`.

### My Example

```py
import pydantic


# _data[variable] = value
_data: dict[str, float] = {
    'f1': 0.1,
    'f2': 0.2,
}


# field name from dict keys
print(
    pydantic.create_model(
        'Model1',
        **{_key: (float, pydantic.Field(default=None)) for _key in _data},
    )().model_dump()
)
# > {'f1': None, 'f2': None}

# and default from dict values
print(
    pydantic.create_model(
        'Model2',
        **{_key: (float, pydantic.Field(default=_data.get(_key))) for _key in _data},
    )().model_dump()
)
# > {'f1': 0.1, 'f2': 0.2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `__pydantic_extra__` to [allow extra fields](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#extra-fields) to be passed to the model and then validating them after they have been posted, which solved the issue in this situation

```py
import pydantic
import my_data

_data = my_data.load() # _data[variable] = value

class MyModel(pydantic.BaseModel):

    # allow additional variables to be passed to the model; 
    # expects a string -> float mapping
    model_config = pydantic.ConfigDict(extra='allow')
    __pydantic_extra__: Dict[str, float]

    @pydantic.model_validator(mode='before')
    @classmethod
    def check_valid_extra(cls, data: Any) -> Any:
        valid_keys = set(_data.keys())
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            for key in data:
                if key not in valid_keys:
                    raise ValueError(
                        f'key "{key}" not found in valid keys: {valid_keys}'
                    )
        return data
```